# Can HTMLMediaElement.play() be scheduled exactly?

Tags: webkit, mobile-safari, web-audio-api

Background: I'm developing a WebAudio-compatible version of MusicFolder 2, a gapless-playback capable media player. It needs to support both very large audio files (hours) and mixes that have been split up into individual audio files that need to be played back end to end without any noticeable audio drop between tracks.

I've tried using decodeAudioData and two instances of AudioBufferSourceNode that take turns, but memory consumption is far too high with large audio files, especially since various Webaudio implementations fail to garbage collect (known bugs).

As an alternative I've implemented a version around HTMLMediaElement and its corresponding source AudioNode, but here the problem is that I cannot exactly schedule the start of the audio element for gapless playback. I've tried various methods like calling .play() on a second audio element with a GainNode set to 0, and then switching to that once the other one finished playing ("ended" event) and then setting .currentTime to 0, but even seeking an already playing element to 0 takes too long.

Is there any way to speed up .play() or seeking, or scheduling either of them to an exact time?

In the production implementation in the App Store, I use iOS' native AVAudioPlayer, which has the "prepareToPlay" function which can be called upfront and ensures immediate playback when calling "play".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can not be scheduled exactly. First of all, (like you said) seeking is not instant and will probably vary per browser. Secondly, called the play method will have to be done in the main javascript thread which is not as accurate (60 times per second, if there is nothing else going on that interferes) as you would get when scheduling with the Web Audio API (which would give you sample accurate scheduling: 44.1k times per second).

Comment: Yep, thought as much (I've already finished the WebAudio-based implementation with sample-accurate scheduling, but as I said it consumes too much memory). Oh well, maybe I should officially request adding a "prepareToPlay" method to HTMLMediaElement.